# scope in call back function in setTimeout() in nodejs 8

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using nodejs 8 and class feature, but found this binding is unexpected.

In my below code, xxx variable should be accessible in the closure created by setTimeout, but it is not. Why?

```
class Wechat {

  constructor(option) {
    this.option = option


  }

  verifySource() {
    console.log('verify source...')
  }

  async setMenu() {
    console.log('setMenu...')
    let thisObject = this
    let nick = 'nick xu'
    var xxxx = 'xxxx nick xu'
    let accessToken = await this.getAccessToken()
    console.log('accessToken:', accessToken)
    setTimeout( function() {
      // let abc = await thisObject.getAccessToken()
      // no access to xxxx and nick variables
      // this point to Timeout object
      console.log('2nd time token:', '000000')
    }, 5000 )
    return Promise.resolve(33)
  }




  async getAccessToken() {
    /*
    this.access_token = 'kkkkkk'
    this.expires_in = 7200
    this.access_token_receive_time = 123456
    */
    const timeBuffer = 60 * 10 * 1000 // 10 min
    if (this.access_token && this.expires_in && this.access_token_receive_time) {
      // if any of the above data exist
      // check expire
      let currentTime = new Date().getTime() 
      if (currentTime - this.access_token_receive_time > timeBuffer + this.expires_in * 1000) {
        // token is valid

        return this.access_token
      }
    }

    let result = await rp.get(config.baseUrl + '/token?' + 
      'grant_type=client_credential&appid=' + config.appID +
      '&secret=' + config.appSecret)
    let resultJson = JSON.parse(result)
    console.log('result of token request:', result)
    this.access_token = resultJson.access_token
    this.expires_in = resultJson.expires_in
    this.access_token_receive_time = new Date().getTime()
    return this.access_token

  }

  static distance() {
    console.log('static method distance')
  }
}
```

when at the debug inside the setTimeout callback. 
[image]

this point to Timeout. What is going on? 
[image]

check the watcher, xxxx and nick are not available...
[image]

Comment: You seem to be asking about two unrelated things here. In the console you're checking `this`, but the `xxxx` and `nick` variables have nothing to do with `this`, they're local variables within `setMenu()`.

Comment: In the setTimeout callback, xxxx and nick variable should be available, since they are in outer closure. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. How were you trying to use them? There's nothing in the code shown that tries to use them.

Comment: according to debug result, they are not available.

Comment: What debug result? The debug screenshots in the question aren't trying to reference those variables either. Try `console.log(xxxx)` in the callback and see what happens.

Comment: just update question with new picture. xxxx is not available in the watcher

Comment: Again, what happens if you try `console.log(xxxx)` in the callback? Also, what do you see if you expand the "Closure (setMenu)" option under the "Scope"?

Comment: gosh... it is shown as not available in watcher, undefined error if I type 'xxxx' in console at break point, but but if I console.log(xxxx), it works. very strange... it is different from my previous experience. Is there an explanation?

Comment: The debugger is simply not perfect in showing access to parent scoped variables.  I've seen this many times.  I don't know why.  It's some limitation or bug in the debugger.  Regular Javascript code has no problem accessing them.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to bind correct "this

```html
setTimeout.call(this, function(){}) //or put whatever scope you want for this
```

if you wanted add argument in settimeout, you can use this

```html
let thisObject = this
    let nick = 'nick xu'
    var xxxx = 'xxxx nick xu'
    
    setTimeout (function (thisObject,nick,xxxx) {},1000,thisObject,nick,xxxx);
```

Comment: That is *not* how to bind a value of `this` in the callback, that's setting the value of `this` for `setTimeout()` itself (which will result in an error unless the first argument to `.call()` is the global object).